# What are good ways to design or diagram state?

Tags: state, diagram, dataflow-diagram

The issue that prompted me to ask this is a web form that was not persisting data the way I expected it to. That's vague, but the point is, what do you like to do to model state, flow of data, and so forth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll second the whiteboard answer and add that explaining what is *supposed* to be happening, following by verbalizing what the the code is *actually* doing, along with a basic graphic is hugely helpful for any project.

Answer (score 2):

Whiteboard as well, but be familiar with the UML diagrams.  I've had a lot of luck with sequence diagrams--they do a good job of describing the interactions between parts of a system.

I've seen people use state diagrams, but they don't contain as much detailed information--sequence diagrams impressed the hell out of me when I first saw them.

Answer (score 2):

The UML has 2 diagrams that may be useful

[State diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/artifacts/stateMachineDiagram.htm) for modelling state.

[Activity diagrams](http://www.agilemodeling.com/style/activityDiagram.htm) for modelling data flow.

Answer (score 1):

I'll put my obvious (to me) answer, which is to use the whiteboard. Love the whiteboard.

Comment: but what do you put on the whiteboard?

Answer (score 1):

[Graphviz](http://graphviz.org) is a great tool for diagramming state machines (once you've worked them out on the whiteboard).

Answer (score 1):

I think the typical models work fine:

for example - state diagrams

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_diagram

I second the whiteboard use.  They are second to none in working on state, flow, etc.